# Get handle to desktop / shell window

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi, pinvoke

In one of my programs, I need to test if the user is currently focusing the desktop/shell window. Currently, I'm using `GetShellWindow()` from *user32.dll* and compare the result to `GetForegroundWindow()`.

This approach is working until someone changes the desktop wallpaper, but as soon as the wallpaper is changed the handle from `GetShellWindow()` doesn't match the one from `GetForegroundWindow()` anymore and I don't quite get why that is. (**OS:** Windows 7 32bit)

Is there a better approach to check if the desktop is focused? Preferably one that won't be broken if the user changes the wallpaper?

**EDIT:** I designed a workaround: I'm testing the handle to have a child of class `SHELLDLL_DefView`. If it has, the desktop is on focus. Whilst, it's working at my PC that doesn't mean it will work all the time.

Comment: have you tried GetDesktopWindow instead?

Comment: I think I haven't. I may be mistaken but I thought I once read that the ShellWindow is the actual desktop (the one that's present since Win95) whereas DesktopWindow is the one that has already been available before and is actually present behind the ShellWindow…

Comment: Yeah, you are right, GetShellWindow is the right one.  http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/pavely/archive/2011/06/18/getshellwindow-vs-getdesktopwindow.aspx So which process window do you get after changing the wallpaper?

Comment: hmmm… I'm not that experienced with Win32, what's the fastest way to get more information (e.g. window title) from a handle? **EDIT:** tried Spy++ but it can't find the handle on my system??

Comment: Read the blog port I linked, it will give you process name from the handle.

Comment: GetShellWindow -> Progman, seems right to me. The handle I get on the Desktop -> is of class WorkerW and has no title…

Comment: The WorkerW has the following children: "" SHELLDLL_DefView -> "FolderView" SysListView32 -> "" SysHeader32

Comment: Here's C++ to enumerate the children: https://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/70823-enumchildwindows/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The thing changed a little bit since there are slideshows as wallpaper available in Windows 7.
You are right with WorkerW, but this works only with wallpaper is set to slideshow effect.

When there is set the wallpaper mode to slideshow, you have to search for a window of class `WorkerW` and check the children, whether there is a `SHELLDLL_DefView`.
If there is no slideshow, you can use the good old `GetShellWindow()`.

I had the same problem some months ago and I wrote a function for getting the right window. Unfortunately I can't find it. But the following should work. Only the Win32 Imports are missing:

```
public enum DesktopWindow
{
    ProgMan,
    SHELLDLL_DefViewParent,
    SHELLDLL_DefView,
    SysListView32
}

public static IntPtr GetDesktopWindow(DesktopWindow desktopWindow)
{
    IntPtr _ProgMan = GetShellWindow();
    IntPtr _SHELLDLL_DefViewParent = _ProgMan;
    IntPtr _SHELLDLL_DefView = FindWindowEx(_ProgMan, IntPtr.Zero, "SHELLDLL_DefView", null);
    IntPtr _SysListView32 = FindWindowEx(_SHELLDLL_DefView, IntPtr.Zero, "SysListView32", "FolderView");

    if (_SHELLDLL_DefView == IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        EnumWindows((hwnd, lParam) =>
        {
            if (GetClassName(hwnd) == "WorkerW")
            {
                IntPtr child = FindWindowEx(hwnd, IntPtr.Zero, "SHELLDLL_DefView", null);
                if (child != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    _SHELLDLL_DefViewParent = hwnd;
                    _SHELLDLL_DefView = child;
                    _SysListView32 = FindWindowEx(child, IntPtr.Zero, "SysListView32", "FolderView"); ;
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }, IntPtr.Zero);
    }

    switch (desktopWindow)
    {
        case DesktopWindow.ProgMan:
            return _ProgMan;
        case DesktopWindow.SHELLDLL_DefViewParent:
            return _SHELLDLL_DefViewParent;
        case DesktopWindow.SHELLDLL_DefView:
            return _SHELLDLL_DefView;
        case DesktopWindow.SysListView32:
            return _SysListView32;
        default:
            return IntPtr.Zero;
    }
}
```

In your case you would call `GetDesktopWindow(DesktopWindow.SHELLDLL_DefViewParent);` to get the top-level window for checking whether it is the foreground window.

Comment: Thanks, I already had a workaround myself. I think your answer is not 100% correct though, as I didn't have a slideshow yet GetShellWindow() failed…

Comment: Source: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/639486/Save-and-restore-icon-positions-on-desktop

Answer (score 6):

Here is a workaround that uses `GetClassName()` to detect if the desktop is active:

- When Windows first starts, the desktop's Class is "Progman"
- After changing the wallpaper, the desktop's Class will be "WorkerW"

You can test against these to see if the desktop is focused.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int GetForegroundWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int GetClassName(int hWnd, StringBuilder lpClassName, int nMaxCount);

public void GetActiveWindow() {
    const int maxChars = 256;
    int handle = 0;
    StringBuilder className = new StringBuilder(maxChars);

    handle = GetForegroundWindow();

    if (GetClassName(handle, className, maxChars) > 0) {
        string cName = className.ToString();
        if (cName == "Progman" || cName == "WorkerW") {
            // desktop is active
        } else {
            // desktop is not active
        }
    }
}
```