# How to get accurate window position of Microsoft Word document?

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, ms-word

I'm trying to "dock" an app to the left of MS Word.

However, the .Left property of the Word window seems to be wrong - like it's scaled somehow.

When the window is close to the far left (0), the returned value for .Left is close to what I'd expect - accurate.

The further I move Word to the right, the more inaccurate it gets. 
If I move it to my left monitor, the same pattern happens - the further negative the more inaccurate.

I've tried retrieving the .Left value in two ways: by p/invoking to FindWindowByCaption(), and then calling GetWindowRect(), and also by using COM Interop to access the window.

Using the first technique against calculator.exe brings back the correct value, so I assume it's not got anything to do with DPI.

Comment: Great! Using MapWindowPoints and HWND_DESKTOP (0) worked - pls post as answer.

Comment: Have deleted the comment and inserted as answer. Ok ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did You try to get the primary screen, and translate the returned coordinates to Client like GetCLientRect ? This seems to be Your solution : [How do I find position of a Win32 control/window relative to its parent window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18034975/how-do-i-find-position-of-a-win32-control-window-relative-to-its-parent-window)
where parent window will be 0 ( Desktop ).